# Parallel execution of a function in the infinite loop

Tags: python, multithreading, while-loop, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

The structure of my code is as follows:

```
while True:
    if(sensor_data_should_be_saved == True):
       start_timer()
       my_file = open_file_for_sensor_data()
       start_detect = True
       sensor_data_should_be_saved = False

    if(start_detect == True):
       timer_done = check_timer()
       save_sensor_data(my_file)
       if(timer_done == True):
          close_file(my_file)
          output = calculate(my_file)
          draw_heatmap(output)
          start_detect = False

    sensor_data_should_be_saved = read_data_from_sensor()
    update_UI_with_new_data()
```

The problem is that `calculate()` function takes some time and during this time (which is about 0.5s) UI freezes and `read_data_from_sensor()` can't be executed. So `calculate()` function should be non-blocking and program should continue while loop. When the function is done, the program should continue from `draw_heatmap(output)`. I don't know if multithreading is useful here. What's the appropriate approach to prevent UI freezing in this code?

Edit: Note that `calculate()` function only sends the `my_file` to a neural network for getting the result of classification. So it doesn't contain an IO operation.

Comment: If the function is bound by the IO operation and can be rewrite, it is better to use async operations. Otherwise, multithreading can be used instead. Not that it is not meant to be faster unless the computation is IO bound because of the GIL. Also multithreading is generally not as great as async as it force you to care about parallel stuff often causing issues (eg. lock, synchronization, race conditions, etc.), and sometime more than it solves.

Comment: @JérômeRichard The `calculate()` function only sends the `my_file` to a neural network for the classification task. So it's not bound by the IO operation.